# How to use in one [formGroup] data to post in webservice

Tags: angular, typescript, nativescript

In my project I use a component that register data. In this component I want to register all data input in local storage, and only 3 parameters I want to post in webservice. So I want to use only one component and [formGroup].

In this [Demo](https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-ng&id=Jzn5Aw) I have project.

```
  this.ConfigurationForm = this.formBuilder.group({
        ipaddwifi: new FormControl("", [Validators.required]),
        wifi: new FormControl("", [Validators.required]),
        pass: new FormControl("", [Validators.required]),
        out1: new FormControl(false),
        out2: new FormControl(false),
        out3: new FormControl(false),
        out4: new FormControl(false)
    });
```

I have this form group, this register:

```
register() {
    // Needs relative path to work with Playground
    let LS = require("../nativescript-localstorage");
    LS.setItem(ConfigurationComponent.CURRENT_CONFIG, JSON.stringify(this.ConfigurationForm.getRawValue()));
    this.routerExtensions.back();
    this.configservice.createConfiguration(
        this.ConfigurationForm.value.ipaddwifi,
        this.ConfigurationForm.value.wifi,
        this.ConfigurationForm.value.pass)
}
```

I want, when I change `wifi` and / or `pass` to post in web service, else not, only to save in local storage

Comment: Where are you getting the old values of `wifi` and `pass` to compare them to the new ones?

Comment: I don't save old value

Comment: Then how exactly are you determining if these values have changed?

Comment: I want them to change one of the values wifi,pass ​​or both to be sent to the server. These new values ​​can I compare with the old values?

Comment: Can you write something for me please?

Comment: Without storing the old value somewhere you won't have a way to compare the new values to anything.

Comment: Yes, but I can't understand how to write code? I'm new programmer, sorry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what is the issue here, it's as simple as writing a `if` condition.

```
     const oldValues = JSON.parse(LS.getItem(ConfigurationComponent.CURRENT_CONFIG) || "{}");
    if (oldValues.ipaddwifi !== ipaddwifi || oldValues.pass !== pass) {
        // Hit your api when new values do not match with old one
    }
```

[Updated Playground](https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-ng&id=Jzn5Aw&v=2)

Answer (score 0):

what i understood from your question is you need to save some data (form object value) to localsotrage and updated when any inputs changed and send that to the api, below i wrote to use steps that i would take to solve this issue.

1. In ngOnInit method check if the localstorage has the form or not if it doesn't have the form you can save the form with the default value (empty values)
   in the local storage.
2. in the register method you will retrieve the form value from the storage.
3. then get the value form the html form.
4. compare between the two object the one you get from the local storage and the one you get from the html (the current one) and check if the value changed then update it.
5. save the updated object to local storage.
6. send the parameter that you need to the api.

Comment: Can you implement it in demo please?